# active admin, a page to manage regular users that fails creating new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

In my rails (3.2.17) application, I use ActiveAdmin(0.6)  in order to manage both administrators and regular users. 
The administrators management comes by default with active admin, and works fine. 

In order to manage regular users, i've created a User model (actually via Devise, but this shouldn't change things since this issue is about users table management)
Now I want to allow users management through ActiveAdmin.
So I've added the 'user.rb' file in my app/admin directory. Below you find the content of the file. 
The page appears, and allows me to start creating a new user. 
But when, in the "creation" form, i press "create user" **it doesn't create it and gets redirected on the same page**.

In the user.rb, you'll notice that i've commented out passoword and password_confirmation.
That's why i use a remote authentication, and so i don't store the password in my db. 
I also removed the column from the migration (and re-aligned the db, of course).

When I press "create user", i get no error on the log, but this weird message:

User Exists (2.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'agostinox@gmail.com' LIMIT 1

But my user **doesn't exist**!

If i create it via SQL statement:

```
insert into users (email, created_at, updated_at) values ('agostinox@gmail.com', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-01');
INSERT 0 1
```

It gets created correctly.
From now on, the user can be also edited in active admin, that is, the "editing" feature seems to work correctly.

I would also appreciate help in debugging this one. It seems to me that ActiveAdmin swallows some error that happens down the road, but I don't know how to configure it to be more verbose in its logs.

This is the users.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  index do
    column :email
    #column :current_sign_in_at
    #column :last_sign_in_at
    #column :sign_in_count
    default_actions
end

filter :email

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "User Details" do
    f.input :email
    #f.input :password
    #f.input :password_confirmation
  end

  f.actions

end
end
```

## edit 1

If I look into the Postgres log, i will see:

2014-04-07 16:36:42 CEST LOG:  statement: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'agostinox@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
2014-04-07 16:36:42 CEST LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK

That is, ActiveAdmin issues a ROLLBACK by itself, not based on an error received from the db. 
I'm quite sure about this because in a similar application that happens to work, there is an 'INSERT INTO...' after the 'SELECT' statement; but here we see that it rollbacks before issuing the INSERT.

Comment: I know for a fact that Devise requires password and password confirmation in order to create a user. You can bypass though (in case you haven't done so already). Why wouldn't you store the password in your DB? any particular reason ?
Look at this wiki from Devise:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up
It might be doing something similar to what you're looking for?

Comment: We have a "central" application that hosts the user credentials, then many "little" application that rely on it, it clearly wouldn't be feasible that each one had its user-credentials database.